# JAVA Retorno de un arreglo de registros

Tags: java, netbeans, return

Estoy intentando que una función me retorne un arreglo de registros, pero me aparece un error en el retorno que dice "Cannot find symbol". Este es el código:

```
import java.io.*;

public class personas {
    public int tipo;
    public int estado;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    public int cedula;
    public String nombre;
    public String apellido;
    public String sexo;
    public String direccion;
    
    public personas[] lectura(String ruta){
        try {
         FileReader sFichero = new FileReader(ruta);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(sFichero);
         String linea = null;
         int conteo = 0;
         
         while((linea = br.readLine())!= null){
             conteo += 1;
         }
         personas persona[] = new personas[conteo];         
                
        int i = 0;
        while((linea = br.readLine()) != null && i < conteo){
            persona[i] = new personas();
            String temporal[] = linea.split(";");
            persona[i].tipo = Integer.parseInt(temporal[0]);
            persona[i].estado = Integer.parseInt(temporal[1]);
            persona[i].username = temporal[2];
            persona[i].password = temporal[3];
            persona[i].cedula = Integer.parseInt(temporal[4]);
            persona[i].nombre = temporal[5];
            persona[i].apellido = temporal[6];
            persona[i].sexo = temporal[7];
            persona[i].direccion = temporal[8];
            i += 1;
        }
         
         br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getCause();
        }
        
        return persona;        
    }
}
```

En el return me aparece el error que les comenté previamente. en temporal se están guardando los datos de un .txt que tiene la misma cantidad de datos que admite el arreglo persona. Ya intenté cambiando de ubicación la función y colocando `paquete.persona[] lectura()` pero me sigue apareciendo el error. Al parecer me está tomando el retorno como una variable en lugar de un arreglo.

Les agradecería mucho si me ayudan a encontrar una solución al problema; solo necesito que funcione ese retorno.

Comment: no encuentro el problema.. pero si veo otro.. y es que recorres el archivo dos veces.. pero como no reseteaste el puntero, la segundo vez no recorre nada.... porque quedo al final del archivo...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Entonces debería colocar un br.close después del primer y después del segundo recorrido?

Comment: y.. pensa que si saliste del primer while, no vas a entrar al segundo porque es la misma condicion de salida del primero... deberias resetear ese buffer de alguna forma....

Answer (score 0):

El problema de no saber de antemano cuantos objetos se van a usar, se resuelve almacenandolos en una lista (que es mutable, a diferencia de un array), no se si es demasiado tarde, pero te dejo este código como guía...

```
public personas[] lectura( String ruta ) {
    try {
         FileReader sFichero = new FileReader( ruta );
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( sFichero );
         String linea = null;
         int conteo = 0;
    
            // creamos la lista
         List<personas> per = new ArrayList<>();

         while(( linea = br.readLine() ) != null ) {

               // creamos el objeto persona (parece mentira, pero los nombres de las
               // clases en mayúsculas, ayudan a entender el código
            personas persona = new personas();
            String temporal[] = linea.split( ";" );
            persona.tipo = Integer.parseInt(temporal[0]);
            persona.estado = Integer.parseInt(temporal[1]);
            persona.username = temporal[2];
            persona.password = temporal[3];
            persona.cedula = Integer.parseInt(temporal[4]);
            persona.nombre = temporal[5];
            persona.apellido = temporal[6];
            persona.sexo = temporal[7];
            persona.direccion = temporal[8];

               // agregamos el objeto a la lista
            per.add( persona );
        }         
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.getCause();
    }    

       // si necesitamos devolver un array, efectuamos la copia
    personas persona[] = new personas[ per.size() ];  
    for( int i = 0; i < per.size(); i++ ) {
       persona[ i ] = per.get( i );         
    }
    return persona;        
}
```